# How to make row background-color fullwidth when surrounding div is a container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website with bootstrap, and I have three divs with the class of row inside of a parent div with a class of container. I want to make the middle row's background color lightblue and fullwidth. I don't know how to  do this. Please help!

(Make sure that the preview pane is wide enough to see the problem)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/oxq5wxg.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa83af6f06.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Road2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3D-Cool-Image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
            <h5 class="text-right">Content goes here.</h5>
            <p class="text-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-primary">
        <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
            <h5 class="">Content goes here.</h5>
            <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3D-Cool-Image.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3D-Cool-Image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
            <h5 class="text-right">Content goes here.</h5>
            <p class="text-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </main>
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Luke Darius

Comment: Please press the full page button option after you cick run code snippe

Comment: do you mean 1st row and last row should not be in full width but middle row should be full width???

Comment: No, I want content in rows to be in the container but the background should be full width for center row